# java.util.InputMismatchException in Getting String From The Keyboard

Tags: java, exception

### CODE

```
package info.code;

import java.util.Scanner;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class GetDataFromKeyBoardAndStoreInDB {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

  Product p = new Product();
  p.setPid(s.nextInt());
  p.setName(s.next());
  p.setPrice(s.nextDouble());

  Configuration cfg = new Configuration(); 
  cfg.configure();
  SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
  Session hsession = sf.openSession();
  hsession.beginTransaction();

  hsession.save(p);

  hsession.getTransaction().commit();
  hsession.close();
  sf.close();
}

}
```

### INPUT

```
115
Hello World
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2387)
    at info.code.GetDataFromKeyBoardAndStoreInDB.main(GetDataFromKeyBoardAndStoreInDB.java:18)
```

-- The above code is working fine when supplied HelloWorld as input but not when supplied Hello World
. Is this method doesn't accept String with space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code

```
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

  Product p = new Product();
  p.setPid(s.nextInt());
  p.setName(s.next().concat(s.nextLine()));
  p.setPrice(s.nextDouble());
```

### Input

333

Hello World Am Fine // We can have any number of tokens of String here ( But should not cross the limit declared in DB )

6000

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Hibernate: insert into HIB.PRODUCT (NAME, PRICE, PID) values (?, ?, ?)

### Output

PID        NAME                             PRICE

333    Hello World Am Fine                   6000

### CASE - 1

If our code is

```
  p.setPid(s.nextInt());
  p.setName(s.nextLine());
  p.setPrice(s.nextDouble());
```

then , if we supply ' Hello World ' as input for parameter to setName(); , it only take 'World' as input becasue scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method (readLine()) returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end.

Hence for the same input ( as given above ) the output will be

PID NAME                             PRICE

333 World                               6000

### CASE - 2 ( Solution to the Problem)

If our code is

```
          p.setPid(s.nextInt());
          p.setName(s.next().concat(s.nextLine());
          p.setPrice(s.nextDouble());
```

then we get the expected output. As first we get the String using s.next(); method, then we concat the skipped String ( skipped by s.next() ); using concat() method to our old String by reading that skipped String using nextLine(); method

### Conclusion

For readLine(); method

Scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Here for `Hello World` `next` will consider `Hello` (*Only*) as token and `nextDouble` takes `World`(*This causes* `Exception`) as input as both are separated by space.Use `nextLine` instead if you want to pass multiple words in second input.

Because `next` method reads upto space.

You can use `hasNextDouble`,`hasNextInt` or `hasNext` methods to check or Surround your code with `try-catch`.

---

As you are mixing up `nextInt()` and `nextLine()` there will be issue in *newLine* character which wasn't read by `nextInt`.

So i suggest you to do it like this.

```
Product p = new Product();
p.setPid(s.nextInt());
s.nextLine();//to remove newLine character inconvinience Skip Line
p.setName(s.nextLine());
p.setPrice(s.nextDouble());
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Scanner` breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace and `InputMismatchException` is thrown if the next token does not match the `Integer`/`String`/`Double`/... regular expression (depending on the method you call), or is out of range. That is why this exception is thrown in case of using space with `Hello World`(3rd token is of type `String` instead of `double`).

Comment: So, can't we supply a String with space in between, when using Scanner

Answer (score 1):

You are using s.next() to read the input, `Hello world` in which `Hello` and `World` are separated by space, which means `s.next()` will read the `Hello` token, and the `World` token hence goes to `s.nextDouble(World)` , which produces exception.

Use `s.nextLine()` for reading , `Hello World`

Comment: The nextInt() is not reading the next `\n` character, either provide your input in the form `1 hello world \n 2.3`, that is separate int and String input with a space rather than `\n` char. OR Insert a `s.nextLine()` after the `s.nextInt()`,Like TAsk said, now it will work.